# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, is there a way to configure a linked directory folder path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, configuration, anchor, razor-pages

I have links to files in a network shared directory on a razor page that I would like to configure in the appsettings.json file, but I have not been able to find a way to use the configured key inside the cshtml anchor tag. Is there a way to do this using the razor syntax?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: ?What? Could you "Edit" your post and show us an example?

Comment: Do you mean you stored the directory folder path in the appsettings.json file, and you want to get this value and add it in the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have stored the directory path in the appsettings.json file and you want to get the path from the appsettings.json file and uses the value in the anchor tag, right? If that is the case, you could try to use the following methods to use the configuration In Razor Pages.

Add File node in the appsettings.json file:

```
    { 
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "File": {
        "FilePath": "https://learn.microsoft.com/"
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

1. Use the @inject directive in Razor page(index.cshtml).

   ```
        @using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
        @inject IConfiguration Configuration 

        <a href="@Configuration.GetSection("File")["FilePath"]">Microsoft</a>
   ```
2. Use ViewData or ViewBag to store the path and display it in the anchor tag.

   Code in the .cshtml.cs file:

   ```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public IndexModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {           
            ViewData["config"] = _configuration["File:FilePath"]; //get the configuration key value.
        } 
    }
   ```

   Code in the view page(.cshtml):

   ```
        <a href="@ViewData["config"]">Microsoft</a>
   ```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Since these documents are in a network share, my previous link to the file that I want to open looked like: <a href="file://\\server\folder\anotherfolder\document.docx">link text</a>   This structure doesn't work when entered in the folder path value in the appsettings.json file, like so: "file": { "filepath": "file:////\\\\server\\folder\\anotherfolder\\document.docx". Would I have to create another key:value pair to hold the "file://" piece of the file path, and then concatenate it somehow?

Comment: I figured it out, there was a typo in my code that I wasn't seeing. The solution provided by Zhi Lv works!